# Login to the Azure-container-service fails with error 'bool' object has no attribute 'rstrip' using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-container-service

Issue :
az acr login --name test1acr

Azure CLI version : azure-cli (2.0.24)
docker version :17.12.0-ce

> Error : 'bool' object has no attribute 'rstrip' Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py",
>   line 193, in invoke
>       cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 319, in execute
>       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 292, in execute
>       result = cmd(params)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 169, in **call**
>       return super(AzCliCommand, self).**call**(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/knack/commands.py",
>   line 109, in **call**
>       return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/**init**.py",
>   line 328, in default_command_handler
>       result = op(**command_args)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/custom.py",
>   line 195, in acr_login
>       password=password)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_docker_utils.py",
>   line 194, in get_login_credentials
>       only_refresh_token=True)   File "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_docker_utils.py",
>   line 150, in _get_credentials
>       password = _get_aad_token(login_server, only_refresh_token, repository, permission)   File
>   "/home/vagrant/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_docker_utils.py",
>   line 35, in _get_aad_token
>       login_server = login_server.rstrip('/') AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to move back to 2.0.23 for now, as 2.0.24 introduced a bug.

Comment: Microsoft says that they are pushing out a fix for 2.0.25 on this coming Wed (01/17). See https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5303#issuecomment-358007360

Answer (score 2):

Azure cli context seems missing in the docker utils.
The below changes worked for me by modifying the _docker_utils file

File: /opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_docker_utils.py 
Line Number: 150

```
-            password = _get_aad_token(login_server, only_refresh_token, repository, permission)
+            password = _get_aad_token( cli_ctx , login_server, only_refresh_token, repository, permission)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but now I'm getting a new error "Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: 'The stub received bad data.'" BTW, the file location on Windows is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acr\_docker_utils.py`.